# HOWTO: CurvedAnimation in "Zero to One" Example

Tags: dart, flutter

Can someone show an example of how a CurvedAnimation might be implemented into the [Zero to One](https://medium.com/dartlang/zero-to-one-with-flutter-43b13fd7b354), or just alongside an AnimationController in general?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wherever you would use an animation you can use a `CurvedAnimation` with the original animation as the parent. In this case, you could replace `tween.animate(animation)` with

```
tween.animate(
  new CurvedAnimation(
    parent: animation,
    curve: Curves.ease,
  ),
),
```

Here's a full example that shows the bars animating to the same value using various curves.

[image: screenshot]

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/animation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;

class Bar {
  Bar(this.height);

  final double height;

  static Bar lerp(Bar begin, Bar end, double t) {
    return new Bar(lerpDouble(begin.height, end.height, t));
  }
}

class BarTween extends Tween<Bar> {
  BarTween(Bar begin, Bar end) : super(begin: begin, end: end);

  @override
  Bar lerp(double t) => Bar.lerp(begin, end, t);
}

class BarChartPainter extends CustomPainter {
  static const barWidth = 10.0;

  BarChartPainter(Animation<Bar> animation)
    : animation = animation,
      super(repaint: animation);

  final Animation<Bar> animation;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final bar = animation.value;
    final paint = new Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue[400]
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    canvas.drawRect(
      new Rect.fromLTWH(
        (size.width - barWidth) / 2.0,
        size.height - bar.height,
        barWidth,
        bar.height,
      ),
      paint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(BarChartPainter old) => false;
}

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new ChartPage()));
}

class ChartPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ChartPageState createState() => new ChartPageState();
}

class ChartPageState extends State<ChartPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final random = new Random();
  AnimationController animation;
  BarTween tween;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animation = new AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 900),
      vsync: this,
    );
    tween = new BarTween(new Bar(0.0), new Bar(50.0));
    animation.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animation.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void changeData() {
    setState(() {
      tween = new BarTween(
        tween.evaluate(animation),
        new Bar(600.0 * random.nextDouble()),
      );
      animation.forward(from: 0.0);
    });
  }

  final List<Curve> curves = [
    Curves.bounceIn,
    Curves.bounceInOut,
    Curves.bounceOut,
    Curves.decelerate,
    Curves.ease,
    Curves.easeIn,
    Curves.easeInOut,
    Curves.easeOut,
    Curves.elasticIn,
    Curves.elasticInOut,
    Curves.elasticOut,
    Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: new List.generate(curves.length, (int index) {
            return new CustomPaint(
              painter: new BarChartPainter(
                tween.animate(
                  new CurvedAnimation(
                    parent: animation, curve: curves[index]),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        child: new Icon(Icons.refresh),
        onPressed: changeData,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```